# Unable to access network drive from Elevated command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 problem to access shared folder](https://superuser.com/questions/245718/windows-7-problem-to-access-shared-folder)

I have an existing set of build scripts which registers the COM components after the build. Now I'm doing these things in elvated command prompt[Otherwise it fails]. But fundamentally I can't access the network drives from elevated command prompt. Is there any work around for this?