# Why isn't File Explorer showing my mapped drives?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, mapped-drive

I'm using Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

My application (that was run as administrator) maps a folder from D drive to a network drive Z using the Windows Network API `wnetaddconnection2()`.

When I opened File Explorer, I couldn't see the Z drive. However, when I opened other applications (e.g., Visual Studio) in Admin mode and browse to This PC folder, I'm able to see the Z drive under Network Location.

Why and how to solve this issue of mapped drives not showing up straight away after being mapped?

---

This issue does not happen

- in Windows 7 OR
- when my application is not run as administrator OR
- after I restart explorer.exe OR
- in Open file dialog in other applications (such as Word, Paint, Visual Studio, etc.)

Note: I have EnabledLinkedConnections set to 1, EnableLUA set to 1.

**Tried Solution**

One solution is to look into a program in Administrative tools called Local Security Policy and disable all the policies related to UAC in Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options (Located in the bottom 15 policies of the list) except UAC:Behaviour..., UAC:Switch... and UAC: Virtualize...

However, I do not want to go down that route due to several issues occuring such as cannot open windows 10 app like Calculator etc.

Comment: A reverse problem and another Windows version however [the same solution](http://superuser.com/a/202840/376602).

Comment: @JosefZ The solutions does not work for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 problem to access shared folder](http://superuser.com/questions/245718/windows-7-problem-to-access-shared-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the UAC, the Shell runs with standard user permissions, it can't see mapped drives which were configured from your application running with admin rights.

There is a [workaround called enabling the option `EnableLinkedConnections`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx):

- Click Start, type regedit in the Start programs and files box, and then press ENTER.
- Locate and then right-click the registry subkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`.
- Point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
- Type `EnableLinkedConnections`, and then press ENTER.
- Right-click `EnableLinkedConnections`, and then click `Modify`.
- In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
- Exit Registry Editor, and then `restart the computer`.

Or you [can apply my hack to run Explorer as admin](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=144776) to also see the mapped drives.

Comment: I have actually already done the EnableLinkedConnections part (as stated in the question) so I tried your hack and it works.